# How to create your own TComment syntax in vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

Is there a way to make your own comment syntax in TComment because I'm currently studying **laravel**
and its native templating which is called **blade** has a syntax for comment which looks like this

```
{{--Hello i'm a comment--}}
```

I would like to be able to toggle with this particular comment syntax when i'm editing a file which has an extension of **.blade.php**

Thanks in advance. If there's a native vim way it would help also. :)

**Update:**

I'm skimming through the help page of Tcomment and i've stumbled upon this function
**tcomment#Comment(beg, end, ...)**, but i don't know how to implement it since i haven't dealt with vimscript yet. Even a small snippet of how this command is implemented could help

Answer (score 2):

If the other suggestion (using an ftplugin, which is preferable since it provides info for other vim features) doesn't work, you could do (in .vimrc):

```
call tcomment#DefineType('blade', '{{--%s--}}')
```

You'd then have to find a way to set the filetype to blade, e.g. (in ~/.vim/filetype.vim)

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.blade.php   setf blade
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a Solution that works for me:

I create a syntax file for the exotic programming language (my language called HRDT).
If I open a file called .script vim change the file type to HRDT.

My .vimrc contains is line:

```
autocmd FileType hrdt set commentstring=\\%s
```

This line automatically change the commentstring from standard *some Text*\ to \some Text .

For commenting I use the very famous NerdCommenter.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that all you need to do is set [`'commentstring'`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27commentstring%27). In your case:

```
setlocal commentstring={{--%s--}}
```

This would probably go in a filetype plugin/`ftplugin`.

Comment: i'm gonna try it. Any idea on how to toggle this comment.

Comment: @noobieAtFirst: I don't use TComment, so I don't know. With vim-commentary, I press backslash three times and it toggles comments on the current line.

Comment: thanks, i'm gonna try that plugin. And it seems like it leverages 'commentstring' for custom comments. and it was written but Tim Pope and his plugins never disappoint. :)

thanks. brb if there's still a problem.

Comment: in your experience is there an unsolved weird bug  or whatsoever in vim-commentary.

Comment: @noobieAtFirst: I actually don't use it very often, but I haven't noticed any problems with it.